# call vs passing object in javascript

Tags: javascript

ive been using call a bit recently in some tutorials I've been following but am more used to passing the object.  I was wondering is it best to use call.  What's the most efficient way?

```
var editor = function(someParam){
 //do something with this
}

var testFunction function(someParam){
  editor.call(this, someParam);
}
```

or

```
var editor = function(obj, someParam){
  var self = obj;
}

var testFunction function(someParam){
  editor(this, someParam);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with passing the object to the function as long as you can structure the function that way.
I see `call` more like a utility if the function cannot be changed anymore and you really have to inject a different `this` context.
Also, consider using the `prototype` approach if your function is bound very close to some object that you want to call the function on.

Also, `call` will be less performant than passing the object to the function, as the injection of a different `this` has some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases call is very useful, for example when adding event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var cb = document.getElementById('myCheckBox');
    cb.addEventListener('change', onchange);
    onchange.call(cb); // sets `cb` as `this` in `onchange` function
});

function onchange(){
    // I'm using 'this' for current element
    if(this.checked)
       alert('checked');
}
```

In this case onchange will be called on window load and every time checkbox checked state changes